# Signal Sigabrt When using IBOutletCollection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

Hi Wonder if someone can help me please.

I have a view controller. This is linked up to my viewcontroller class all ok.

Within the main view i have 3 subviews. I want to set borders etc on these 3 subviews.
So i created a `IBOutletCollection` and wired them all up. No problem. The borders took effect and all was ok.

I then went and changed the background color of each of these 3 views via the storyboard GUI editor and re-run the program now i keep getting signal sigabrt exceptions. Iv put breakpoints on the border setting code and it doesnt even reach there.
If i remove the links to my iboutletcollection then it runs no problem.

I cant understand why its decided to stop working when 3 mins ago everything was fine. Iv turned the color back and still same problem.
I guess im going to have to use 3 iboutlets and set each of their borders etc individually. Unless someone can advise.

My collection i use is:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSMutableSet* <NAME>;
```

Im connecting them up and setting the background color via the storyboard `GUI` editor. The ONLY change i made between it working as i wanted and it beginning to throw exceptions was change the background colors via the `GUI` editor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not declaring your `IBOutletCollection` properly. Try `IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray * subViewContainer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html) (scroll down to the bottom) on `IBOutletCollection` states:

> You can insert this macro only in front of variables typed as NSArray or NSMutableArray.

So change the type from `NSMutableSet *` to `NSMutableArray *`.

Comment: Thats great thanks. This was winding me up. But still cant understand why it worked first time round :| important thing is its fixed now. Many thanks